# Data from more than 1 query - possible union needed?

Tags: union

I have a query (Query A) that pulls data from my Customer table.
I have another query (Query B) that pulls data from a list of records associated with various customers.
-   Every customer on Query B exists on Query A….but not every customer on Query A has a record on Query B

What I’m trying to do is to take 1 field from Query B, and pull it into Query A….but when I do that, it essentially limits the entire scope of Query A to only those customers present on Query B.

Is there a way that I can have Query A display it’s full list of customers, with a column next to it that displays data from Query B only if there is data on Query B?

I hope I’m making sense!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a LEFT JOIN to get all of QueryA  and whatever records exist for QueryB

```
SELECT * FROM QueryA as A LEFT JOIN QueryB as B on A.columnid=B.columnid
```

Comment: That is perfect, thank you so much!  Far far easier than I was expecting!!